# How to find a servlet object by name?

Tags: jsp, servlets

OK, completely noob to JSP here. I need to find the code that handles a form submission, but I did a text search and can't find it at all.

I have this in my web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/flow.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The flow.htm is where the form is posting to. How do I locate the java code that handles the post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same `web.xml` there must be a declaration of `myservlet` servlet similar to this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.YourServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

`com.example.YourServlet` is the class you should investigate (of course in your code it will be a different class). If your form sends the data using POST, look at `doService` method in this class.

Comment: Yup.  And note, if you aren't familiar with java packaging, that the YourServlet class mentioned above (again, yours will be different) will be in a folder called "example" inside a folder called "com" (again, different in your case; the point is that the parts of the package name become nested directories to look inside).

Comment: Bingo, but it leads me to a deep and darker hole -- org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet, which have more xml definitions, lol. this shit is crazy.

Comment: The hole is deeper than you might think :-). But knowledge of Spring MVC (this what you should look for) will certainly pay off. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Find the following entry in the same file :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>the.class.of.the.servlet.handling.the.Request</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

It will give you the class name of the servlet.